# Reduce size of UINavigationBar buttons

Tags: ios, button, uinavigationbar

I noticed that Xcode 7.x interface builder add buttons on the UINavigationBar that are slightly bigger than those used by the standard apps, like the mail app. The add button (+) and back (<) are smaller in the standard apps. I want to keep the standard buttons, but I want them with the same size of the other applications. Do anyone know how to achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: FIXED!

The problem is in XCode. If your app has no Launch Screen declared all Views will appear bigger (higher Navigation Bar with bigger buttons, bigger tab-bar, bigger font for UITableViewCells). I've added a LaunchScreen (storyboard) and, all of a sudden, everything returned back to normal size.

Comment: You must have been testing on a 6+. BarButtons look too small with the launch screen added.

Comment: In that case just change the font. I fixed it that way

Answer (score 0):

Simply modify the size of the images in your assets catalog. Remember to customize each image based on the associated screen resolution.

[image: 1x 2x 3x UINavigationbar Icons]

In the image above, the 1x is what you would see on a smaller/lower resolution device, while 3x is what you would see on a larger/higher resolution product.

Comment: It is not about my custom images, but the standard images of iPhone. On my UiNavigationBar I use only the stock images provided by iOS. Those images are bigger in my application than in the standard apps, like the email app.

Comment: Are you sure that the icons are larger in the email app relative to your application? I remember thinking that the twitter search bar was larger than the search bar in the app store, but after invesigating I discovered that the font size was the only difference. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a practical answer to your question, since Apple's apps do a number of things using private APIs. I would recommend just recreating these icons ('+' is simple for instance) or creating something similar.

Comment: Yes. All standard apps have stock images smaller than mine

Comment: @Sergiob I notice the same behaviour in my own xcode project. I looked at some third party apps, and they just create their own versions. Even the stackexchange app does this. I would definitely be interested in an alternative solution though, if you manage to find one.

Comment: I've noticed that the problem is related to the default font used by the app.I'm trying to see if xcode has the possibility to set the font size for the whole app. After creating a new project I noticed that the new app has normal size buttons and the font of the Navigation Bar title and UITableCellView labels are smaller. That means somewhere, in the project, the font size is set to a bigger value. I didn't find out where yet, but I'm looking into the issue.

Comment: I have found the problem. See my comment above